Showing that the real part of $z(t) = c_1e^{i \omega t} + c_2e^{-i \omega t}$ can be written as $x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \theta)$
I am trying to confirm this statement, considering $c_1\in \mathbb{C}$, $c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\omega > 0$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}$ .
My attempt to show this is by first performing a substitution considering Euler's formula and expanding the complex constants, such that:
$z(t) = (a_1 + i b_1) [\cos(\omega t) + i \sin(\omega t)]+ (a_2+ i b_2)[\cos(\omega t) - i \sin(\omega t)] $
Now looking only at the real part of this equation:
$Re(z(t)) = (a_1 + a_2)\cos( \omega t) - (b_1 - b_2)\sin(\omega t) $
Here I use the trigonometric identity $\cos(\alpha + \beta) =\cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta $ to compare with  $Re(z(t))$ and get:
$a_1+ a_2 = A \cos\theta$, $b_1-b_2 = A\sin\theta$
Writing $A$ and $\theta$ in terms of the constants:
$A = \sqrt{(a_1+a_2)^2(b_1-b_2)^2}$
$\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{b_1-b_2}{a_1+a_2})$
Such that $Re(z(t)) = A\cos(\omega t + \theta)$
In case $a_1 + a_2 = 0$, the expression $(a_1 + a_2)\cos( \omega t) - (b_1 - b_2)\sin(\omega t) $ simplifies to
$- (b_1 - b_2)\sin(\omega t)  = A \cos(\omega t + \theta) $
with $\theta = \pm \pi/2$
Is there a simpler way to show this statement correct than the way I performed it? Looking forward to understanding it better, thanks.

Notice that ${\rm Re}(c_2e^{-iwt})={\rm Re}(\bar{c_2}e^{iwt})$. It follows
$$
  {\rm Re}(c_1e^{iwt}+c_2e^{-iwt}) = {\rm Re}(c_1e^{iwt}+\bar{c_2}e^{iwt}) = {\rm Re}\left[(c_1+\bar{c_2})e^{iwt}\right].
$$
Clearly, there is a polar decomposition $c_1+\bar{c_2}=re^{i\theta}$, and then
$$
  {\rm Re}(c_1e^{iwt}+c_2e^{-iwt}) = {\rm Re}\left[(c_1+\bar{c_2})e^{iwt}\right] = r\cos(wt+\theta).
$$
